# jQuery offset() error?

Tags: jquery, css

In some cases, the offset() method seems to return an erroneous 0/0 offset

1. With jQuery, on document ready, mouseover an a.TT selector is captured.

   $('.TT').on('mouseover', linkMouseover)
2. On mouseover, a tooltip should be displayed...

   ```
   function linkMouseover() {
                  var $this=$(this);
                  var offset = $this.offset();
                  $('#log').append('id=' + $this.attr('id') + ' offset=l' + offset.left + '/t=' + offset.top + '<br />');
                  /*...*/
   }
   ```

In a combination of absolutely positioned divs, the offset() return 0,0...

Please check code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ysckk2u/3/

Am I missing something? Could it be the result of using css-calc() for positioning?

Comment: `$(this)` is not what you think.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Didn't know you could read my mind... but telling me what it then is would help :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I thought of checking that too, but the code of the OP outputs the id of "this", and it is the id of the link, so I think he might have found a bug in jQuery,

Comment: Strange, even this.getBoundingClientRect() is giving top, left, bottom right offsets of 0, 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Indeed it isn't a bug in jQuery, but something else - the "bad" links don't have an `offsetParent`, which would be required for calculating a global offset.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol As a matter of fact, it is not a bug in jQuery. See the explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why, but when I mouse over a .Div3 element, it triggers a mouseover, a mouseout and another mouseover which in turns shows the element, hides it, and shows it again. Probably the code calculating the offset is called while the element is hidden. All this happens very fast, and we don't see it happening.

However, if you use jQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), instead of mouseover and mouseout, everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/velum/558e83cL/1/

```
function indexReady() {
    // $('.Div3').mouseover(over3);
    // $('.Div3').mouseout(out3);
    $('.Div3').hover(over3, out3);
```

Comment: Of course. Alternatively, use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead (IE-proprietary, jQuery patches support in Chrome/Firefox/etc. because those events are too awesome)

Comment: Hi @wdelaet! Glad to have helped. If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.